# Treat the same XML tag differently depending on the parent with etree/python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm working with a [python script](http://pastebin.com/D9DkQdEv) to parse XML and create a python file from it.

At the top level the XML looks like;

```
<stage id="stage1">
    <initialise>
    </initialise>
    <execute>
    </execute>
</stage>
```

Here is a [sample](http://pastebin.com/vRRxfWiA) of the full XML. Quite complicated stuff.

I've got a parser written to handle most things, but in this instance, is it possible to check up the tree for the `</initialise>` coming before the `<execute>` in order for that to identify differently.

Can you do this using the `elem[x]` type method or maybe XPath?

```
<initialise>
    <variable id="maxLimit" value="0" type="Integer">
        <validate>
            <regularExpression></regularExpression>
        </validate>
        <execute>
        </execute>
    </variable>
</initialise>
<execute> # treat this differently
```

The Python that grabs the execute elements looks like this;

```
def parse_execute(self, elem):

    if elem[0].tag == 'required': #or elem[0].tag == 'variable':
        self.loop(elem)
    else:
        self.out('')
        self.out('def {0}():'.format(elem.tag))
        self.indent()
        self.loop(elem)
        self.dedent()
```

Comment: It's refreshing to see a question which begins *"I'm using XML"*, and then actually proceeds to show valid XML.

Comment: And I forgot to include a link to a sample of the full XML. whoops.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: There is a system running on both python & ASP which reads the XML to run. With this I'm trying to allow the python side to just read python & thus speed up processes.